# ¿Mi archivo no guarda un valor entero en C++?

Tags: c++, archivo

Mi programa consiste en crear un archivo `.dat`, con 3 valores (nombre, edad y país), leer el archivo y mostrar su contenido.

El problema que tengo es que al momento de abrir mi archivo, solo me guarda los valores tipo char. Creo que el error se encuentra en `getchar();`, pero si no lo utilizo no me deja ingresar el país.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct Persona
    {
        char nombre[40];
        int edad;
        char pais[30];
    }est;

int main()
{
    FILE* matatero;
    matatero=fopen("agenda.dat","a+");
       puts("Ingrese el nombre: ");
       gets(est.nombre);
       fprintf(matatero,"%s",est.nombre);
       puts("Ingrese edad: ");
       scanf("%d",&est.edad);
       fscanf(matatero,"%d",&est.edad);
       getchar();
       puts("Ingrese pais: ");
       gets(est.pais);
       fputs(est.pais,matatero);
    fclose(matatero);

    matatero=fopen("agenda.dat","r");
    while(!feof(matatero))
    {
        fgets(est.nombre,40,matatero);
        puts(est.nombre);
        fscanf(matatero,"%d",&est.edad);
        printf("%d",est.edad);
        fgets(est.pais,30,matatero);
        puts(est.pais);
        cout<<endl;
    }
    fclose(matatero);

    return 0;
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Veo que estás usando C++ sin embargo toda la gestión de archivo la realizas con librerías de C. Échale un vistazo a [`fstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream).

Comment: Si gracias @PaperBirdMaster lo he utilizado, el problema es que el catedrático desea que lo hagamos a su modo.

Comment: Estoy en completo desacuerdo con el catedrático >:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
puts("Ingrese el nombre: ");
gets(est.nombre);
fprintf(matatero,"%s",est.nombre);
```

Pides un nombre, lo lees y almacenas el valor en el fichero...

```
puts("Ingrese edad: ");
scanf("%d",&est.edad);
fscanf(matatero,"%d",&est.edad);
```

Pides la edad, la recuperas... y sobreescribes el valor con lo que quiera que se encuentre en el fichero... no suena bien. Sustituye `fscanf` por `fprintf`

Comment: Wow me funciono!
Lo cambie por `fprintf(matatero,"%d",est.edad);`, y ya me lo guardo.